# C - Double pointer is NULL. Linked list structure

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, variadic-functions

I started learning C about a week ago. To somewhat test out my understanding of pointers I have been trying to create a linked list type structure which represents a menu bar you might find in any GUI.

[image: Menubar Example]
`Like this.`

Rather than explaining the kind of structure I came up with I decided it would be easier representing it via a crude diagram... (hope there's no mistakes here).
[image]

So I came up with the following C code. All it does is create a menu structure. It is supposed to loop through the whole menu and output it into text form...

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef enum menu_item_type {
    ITEM,
    MENU,
    TERMINATOR
} menu_item_type;

typedef struct menu_item menu_item;
typedef struct menu_item {
    const char* label; // label text for item shown to user
    menu_item_type type; // item type. see above enum for possibilities
    menu_item** next; // pointer to next item
    menu_item* below; // item below in same menu    
} menu_item;

void menubar(const char* menubar_label, ...);
menu_item* menu(const char* label, ...);
menu_item* menu_va(const char* label, va_list args);
menu_item* item(const char* label);
menu_item* terminator();

/*
    setup menubar. variadic function.
*/
void menubar(const char* menubar_label, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, menubar_label);  
    menu_item* menubar = menu_va(menubar_label, args); // menubar is a menu
    va_end(args);
    
    menu_item* item = menubar;
    menu_item* next;
    int ident = 0;
    do {
        if(item->type == TERMINATOR) {
            ident--; // unindent after submenu finishes
        }else{
            for(int i = 0; i < ident; i++) {
                printf("  "); // ident each submenu further
            }
            printf("[%s]\n", item->label); // print item label
        }
        if(item->type == MENU) {
            ident++; // add ident when submenu starts
        }
        next = *item->next;
        free(item); // item printed. no longer needed.
        item = next;
    } while(item);
}

/*
    single menu/submenu. overload variadic function for menu_va.
*/
menu_item* menu(const char* label, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, label);
    menu_item* menu = menu_va(label, args);
    va_end(args);
    return menu;
}

/*
    create a menu/submenu with a set label. pass items in a va_list.
*/
menu_item* menu_va(const char* label, va_list args) {
    // head item is the item that starts a menu off (e.g item 'File')...
    menu_item* head = item(label); 
    head->type = MENU;
    menu_item* i = head;
    menu_item* next;
    while(i->type != TERMINATOR) {
        next = va_arg(args, menu_item*);
        if(i != head) {
            i->below = next; // next item is item below unless it's head item.
        }
        i->next = &next; // set next item
        i = next;
    }
    // next item after terminator is item below head item
    i->next = &head->below; 
    return head;
}

/*
    create item with label.
*/
menu_item* item(const char* label) {
    menu_item* i = malloc(sizeof(menu_item));
    i->label = label;
    i->type = ITEM;
    i->next = NULL;
    i->below = NULL;
    return i;
}

/*
    create terminator item. signals end of a menu.
*/
menu_item* terminator() {
    menu_item* i = item(NULL);
    i->type = TERMINATOR;
    return i;
}

int main() {
    // menubar structure is...
    menubar("Menubar Test",
        menu("File",
            item("New"),
            item("Save"),
            item("Save As..."),
            menu("Export To...",
                item("PDF File"),
                item("JPG File"),
                terminator()
            ),
            terminator()
        ),
        menu("Edit",
            item("Copy"),
            item("Paste"),
            menu("Remove...", 
                item("All"),
                item("Selection"),
                terminator()
            ),
            item("Undo"),
            terminator()
        ),
        menu("Help",
            item("About"),
            terminator()
        ),
        terminator()
    );
    return 0;
}
```

From this code I wanted output like this:

```
[Menubar Test]
    [File]
        [New]
        [Save]
        [Save As...]
        [Export To...]
            [PDF File]
            [JPG File]
    [Edit]
        [Copy]
        [Paste]
        [Remove...]
            [All]
            [Selection]
        [Undo]
    [Help]
        [About]
```

Instead I get just this:

```
[Menubar Test]
```

Only the first item is printed. I found that the `->next` pointer of the first item is NULL but I really have no idea why. I kind of thought I understood pointers but evidently I'm missing something. This isn't really a problem I know how to debug. Playing about trying to debug it yielded strange results. Sometimes I even found that the pointer address would just randomly change for a unknown reason. (`printf("%p")`). Most of the time though I just ending up with segfaults.

If anyone can point (ha) me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Suggest you simplify your test case. You likely don't need that full menu structure to repro the problem. Start with a much simpler menu structure - easier for you and others to debug. Build up different test cases with increasingly complex menus and don't move on to the next more complicated case until all previous cases pass.

Comment: Why is `next` a `**` ?  You are setting it to the address of a local variable which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: C code does not typically make heavy use of variadic functions, other than the formatted I/O functions in the standard library.  It is uncommon for programs to define their own variadic functions.  Since you're new to C, I would recommend focusing on other language features for the time being.

Comment: Opinions vary, but personally, I recommend avoiding `typedef` under most circumstances.  There are a few situations where a `typedef` can help a lot, but in most cases I find that typedefed type identifiers do not yield enough advantage to offset their inherently obfuscatory nature.  In some cases, such as typedefed object pointer types, the inherent obfuscation is in fact a pretty big negative.  Note well, also, that contrary to its name, `typedef` does not define a new type.  It defines an identifier as an *alias* for another type.  You can always avoid declaring any typedefs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I realized that `typedef` was only an alias for another type. I figured it must be good practice to use though since a lot of libraries I am looking at seem to use them all the time (e.g SDL2). To be honest I can't see how it is obfuscatory? All it means to me is that I don't write `struct menu_item` every time. My use of a variadic function was both curiosity and also that I think it is a nice way of expressing the structure of my menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question. As @John3136 said, setting a pointer to a local variable will not work if you use it outside of your function. It will cause undefined behavior which explains why the symptoms of my original problem were so nonsensical. This seems to me to be a newbie mistake but I'm glad I know better now.

I've amended my code in light of this and it now works great. I am not going to post my updated code because it is not general so probably wouldn't serve very useful.